# Is it necessary to `window.removeEventListener('unload')`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am storing the lastest input data values to `localStorage` before the user leaves the webpage. Writing to `localStorage` is executed on `window.onunload`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const updater = () => {
    updateStorageValue('last_input', input);
  };

  window.addEventListener('unload', updater);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('unload', updater);
}, [input]);
```

Let's say the component (where this `useEffect` was used) was mounted when the user closed/refreshed the tab/window.

I am just curious if removing the `unload` event has any effect while the whole webpage will stop working.

Comment: Yes, removing the unload event here would just be a No Op,. But to be honest I would still keep it there, as it just feels more right.. :)

Comment: @Keith I agree with you on still keeping it. But I am not sure if it is more than just feeling right. Besides, here in `useEffect` the returned callback is not getting called on `unload`.

Comment: Returning a "cleanup function" is _always_ best practice when writing useEffect hooks. Not only will it make things consistent between all useEffects, but it keeps behavior of the component a known quantity and guards against unexpected behavior. Can you be assured, with 100% certainty, that your component will never be unmounted and remounted? What if you later change your mind about routing and cause a situation where that would be the case, but forgot about your missing useEffect cleanup? What if you re-use this code somewhere else where the component might have rerenders?

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't unmount the app components when closing/refreshing the page. So the answer to your question is: No, it doesn't have any effect.

But if it's a normal component living on the page (not mounting just before exit), then the cleanup function should be there to remove the previous `unload` event listener before adding the next one.

Your `useEffect` removes the `unload` event listener and adds a new one when `input` changes. But if you remove the cleanup function, then you will have as many `unload` event listeners as `input` updates.

For example, assume that the `input` value changes in the following order:

```js
'R'
'Re'
'Rea'
'Reac'
'React'
```

In this case, these functions will be called on the `unload` event:

```js
updateStorageValue('last_input', 'R');
updateStorageValue('last_input', 'Re');
updateStorageValue('last_input', 'Rea');
updateStorageValue('last_input', 'Reac');
updateStorageValue('last_input', 'React');
```